# Any clue on how to protect my website's source code?

Tags: javascript, html, encryption

So I have a website in html and I want to protect its source code from visitors.

I was looking around for some time and everyone seem to agree that it was impossible to do, the only thing that could be done is to disable right click.

And yet I found this website that is indeed protected.

http://tradesteamlatino.tk/,

So, No matter where you go it will always display the same source code, I'm not sure if it is 100% secure but it will still protect the code from most users.

How could this be done?

Comment: Why would you want to? If there's sensitive information, using a server side language. The source output of websites is intended to be visible, for browsers to be able to read it. Not to mention it will probably ruin your crawlability for search engines.

Comment: The site You mention *does* change - it contains a <frame> that points to http://tradesteamlatino.weebly.com/ and there the source code changes on every click.

Comment: It uses frames and you can view source and check the frame's source to get to content. So no!! There's no way you can protect the source code directly

Comment: You want to protect your source code on the internet? Don't put your source code on the internet.

Comment: The best way is not to publish it. :D

Comment: You can create dynamic code to fetch data using server side scripting but the client side script is not hiddable, if you use angularjs , a partially data can be hidden.

Comment: I swear I've actually read forums posts asking how a given site did to hide source code—just to find the site had two dozen carriage returns before the `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

As your internet browser needs the code to display something, I would say that completly hiding HTML and/or JS code is impossible.

Here's an article I found about that, the conclusion is quite the same as mine.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/article.php/3875651/Web-Developer-Class-How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code.htm